# Swapping red with green, vice versa

Tags: javascript

I've been working on this problem for a while now and am not able to figure out what I need to fix my code. I should be able to swap the color red with green, but in my example I keep getting an error (I can set the red to green, but not vice versa. Can someone take a look at where I've gone wrong?

```
function swapRedGreen(pixel){

pixel.setRed(pixel.getGreen());
pixel.setGreen(pixel.getRed());
}
var image = new SimpleImage("eastereggs.jpg");
print(image);
for(var pix of image.values()){
    swapRedGreen(pix);
}
print(image);
```

Comment: homework assignment?  Regardless, there's not enough to go on here.  Where is your print function declared?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a temporary variable, because red has changed by the time you try to set green.

```
var oldRed = pixel.getRed();

pixel.setRed(pixel.getGreen());
pixel.setGreen(oldRed);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a temporary variable to swap values of Red and Green

```
var img = new SimpleImage("rodger.png")
print(img)

function swapRedGreen(pixel){
        x = pixel.getRed();
        pixel.setRed(pixel.getGreen());
        pixel.setGreen(x);
    }

for (var pix of img.values()){
    swapRedGreen(pix)
}
print(img)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code i came up with to solve this problem. The approach is to create two variables, one is initialized with the red and the other one is initialized with the green and just swap them around later on.

```
    var MyImage = new SimpleImage("eastereggs.jpg");
    print(MyImage);

    function swapRedGreen(pixel) {  
        var newGreen = pixel.getRed();  
        var newRed = pixel.getGreen();  
        pixel.setGreen(newGreen);   
        pixel.setRed(newRed);   
        return pixel;
    }

    for (var pix of MyImage.values()){
        swapRedGreen(pix);
    }
    print(MyImage);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
       var image = new SimpleImage("usain.jpg");
function swapRedGreen(image){
    for (var pixel of image.values()){
    pixel. setRed(pixel.getGreen());
    pixel. setGreen(pixel. getRed());

    }
}
  swapRedGreen(image);
    print(image);
```

Comment: This question already have an answer. And also your code would provide wrong result because you calling `pixel.getRed()` after `pixel.setRed` and miss old red value

Answer (score -1):

```
var img = new SimpleImage("eastereggs.jpg");

function swapRedGreen (pixl) {
    var oldRed = pixl.getRed();
    pixl.setRed (pixl.getGreen());
    pixl.setGreen (oldRed);

}
for (var pix of img.values()) {
    swapRedGreen(pix);
}

print (img);
```

Comment: This combination of A.K. and axelduch worked for me.

Comment: Hi Thomas, thanks for your answer. Although it might be helpful, it could be better if you explain your code.